jest mock "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property"
I am using jest 29.7.0
I have a module named message.js with
export async function send() {...}

Then this module is used in another file handler.js
import {send} from './message.js'

export default async function handle(){
    // Do stuf
    await send()
    // More stuf
}

Then in my test I want to mock the send function.
I tried with
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
import handle from "../../handler.js"
import * as message from "../../message.js"
it("Should test handle", function(){
    const spy = jest.spyOn(message, 'send').mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve());
    await handle();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})

But the spyOn is throwing TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'send' of object '[object Module]'
I also tried with
message.send = jest.fn();

But I have the same issue
I also tried adding
jest.mock('../../message.js', () => ({
  __esModule: true, 
  send: jest.fn(()=>Promise.resolve('mocked')),
}));

after, before the import, in the test, in an before
But in each cases I have the same issue calling message .send.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve)  TypeError: message.send.mockReturnValue is not a function
Removing message.send.mockReturnValue the mocked function is not called but the original one.
I also tried with
Object.defineProperty(message, "send", {
  value: jest.fn(),
  configurable: true,
  writable: true
});

Before calling jest.spyOn but it throws TypeError: Cannot redefine property: send
I am running jest with the following command NODE_OPTIONS=\"$NODE_OPTIONS --experimental-vm-modules\" jest

What are you actually trying to test here?

I want to test a function from an other file which is using send from the message.js file

The second attempt with the jest.mock makes more sense, then, but if you're using ES modules note https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#module-mocking-in-esm. If that doesn't work give a [mre].

Just added a minimal reproducible example

I found the solution.
The following test code works
import { jest } from '@jest/globals'

jest.unstable_mockModule("../../message.js", () => {
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        send: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('mocked'))
    }
})

const handle = (await import("../../handler.js")).default;

